# aws hosting works only via vpn

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I have deployed my app to aws lightsail and assigned it to a DNS record.

I can access it by domain name using a VPN, but if I try to access from Ukraine I cannot. If I try to access via IP - everything is good

Comment: What steps have you taken?

Comment: I created dns zone and added A record. Once I saw a message about ssl certificate (https is not set yet)

Comment: So does it not connect to your host, can it resolve it?

Comment: "I investigated that IT WORKS but via vpn access", did you checked the fire wall of light sale might be possible it just allowing `VPN IP`? click on `lightsail` instance then `-> networking -> firewall ` check allowed IPs.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I do not understand but if it works by url through vpn - isn't it connected? Or should I check it in some way?

Comment: if it's working with VPN only then it mean something in between restricting connection from outside.

Comment: how can I check it? and clarify what is wrong?

Comment: Did you check Firewall that I mentioned in the comment and mentioned username in the comment so I'll get notifications

Comment: @Adiii Where these firewall should be checked? I didn't set up it in aws

Comment: Light sail come with defaul firewall, you can check this using light sale then click on the light instance then network under network section you'll see firewall

Comment: @Adiii There are 3 rules about http(80), rdp (3389) and ssh(22).Nothing more

Comment: by the way, it is accessible by ip, but by domain name -no/Maybe it will help